# get auto formatted date from kendo ui datepicker value() method

Tags: php, laravel-4, kendo-datepicker

By default output of KendoDatePicker value

> `$("#datepicker").data('kendoDatePicker').value()`

is

> Fri Jan 09 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (Azores Standard Time)

How do i change it to something like this:

> 09/01/2015

or

> Fri Jan 09 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0600

I know that the output value can be formatted with this function:

> kendo.format(.....)

But when using datePicker on grid popup editor then i have no option to format the value before sending to the server. I am using laravel for backend. And laravel is getting hard time getting date from that value. I have tried with several functions to format the data : Carbon,date,date_create... and none of them works. Some produces errors :

> double datetime specification

some functions work if the string datetime is :

> Fri Jan 09 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0600

insted of

> Fri Jan 09 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (Azores Standard Time)

Is there any way to globally set the format for value() method output? 
Please help, i have spent too much time for getting this done and i am going to miss the deadline.

Comment: You can format your date in Kendo grid itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366310/format-of-date-selected-from-kendo-datepicker-inside-kendo-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my answer after lots of search : use 'parse'

```
model:{
                id:'id',
                fields:{
                    appointment_date: { 
                        type: "date",
                        parse:function(){
                          var parsed=kendo.parseDate(date);
                          if (!parsed) return null;
                          return kendo.format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",parsed);
                     }
                    },
                    .........
                    .............
                }
            }
```